# Showing a function attains its maximum (proof strategy)

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

This is a question for a class, so please try to avoid posting full answers. I'd like to ask about the strategy of proof for showing that the mapping $\mathbf{R}^n\to\mathbf{R}$ given by $x\mapsto\langle Ax,x\rangle,$ where $A$ is an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix with real entries, attains its maximum on the unit $n$-sphere $S^{n-1},$ with the Euclidean norm.

My current thinking is that since $S^{n-1}$ is compact, if I can show that $f$ is continuous then it must attain its supremum on $S^{n-1}.$ Actually dealing with an expression for $f$  is a bit tedious, and I find that if
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & \cdots & a_{n1}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nn}\end{array}\right)$$ is my matrix, then I get a formula like
$$\langle Ax,x\rangle=\left(a_{11}x_1+a_{21}x_2+\cdots+a_{n1}\right)x_1+\left(a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2+\cdots+a_{n1}x_n\right)x_2+\cdots+\left(a_{n1}x_1+a_{n2}x_2+\cdots+a_{nn}x_n\right)x_n$$ which looks to define a quadratic (I do know the double sum formula, but I chose not to write it, since it seems more 'intuitive' this way, since I can see how the square terms come out, and certain terms are identical). Can I simply state at this point that since $\langle Ax,x\rangle$ defines a polynomial that the mapping $x\mapsto\langle Ax,x\rangle$ is continuous and hence attains its maximum on $S^{n-1},$ or am I missing something? I feel like I'm being a bit skimpy on "rigor" here, but the idea seems to make sense to me.

I'd also appreciate any other directions someone might have for a possible proof, if my idea won't work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** : Every real valued function defined on a compact set of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is bounded and attains its bounds. (You already thought to use this).

Note that $(x,y) \, \longmapsto \, \left\langle x,y \right\rangle$ is bilinear, hence continuous on $\mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $x \, \mapsto \, Ax$ is linear, hence continuous on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Therefore, $x \, \mapsto \, \left\langle Ax,x \right\rangle$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: Oh for God's sake. Thank you.

Comment: Just one question, do you know if this also follows from the fact that a real symmetric square matrix defines a quadratic? I'd just like to know whether my original method would've worked, just so I know both what the simplest answer was and whether something was wrong/right for future reference.

Comment: @user184512 : Yes, you could also say that $x \, \mapsto \, \left\langle Ax,x \right\rangle$ is polynomial in $x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}$ hence continuous.

Comment: Great, thanks for your help. I'm just waiting until I can accept this answer, will give +1 vote when I can log back in to my other account.